# Automate notepad++ editing csv file using script

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have this code that generates a .csv file of data, however the formatting is off due to the escapechar (can't fix this). I need to make all the double spaces into single spaces. I can do this in notepad++ with replace all, so I've written a python script using a notepad++ plugin that does this. Now I'd like to automate opening the file and running the script; is this possible using a batch file? Is there a better way to do this?

Example of before and after format needed:

```
"_time","location"
"2018-04-03T08:32:45.565000-0400","(0 , 3)"
"2018-04-03T08:32:45.565000-0400","(2 , 5)"


"_time","location"
"2018-04-03T08:32:45.565000-0400","(0,3)"
"2018-04-03T08:32:45.565000-0400","(2,5)"
```

Comment: You could write a .py file and run it vs. a set of CVS in a folder via `./myfile.py *` You could then save it as a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all with Python.
Just read the file and use the string replace method. Probably you will create a temporary file with the adjustments and then rename it.  Something like:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        newline = line.replace("  ", " ") #two spaces become one space
        #... write newline to temp file, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this; however it messes up a lot of formatting since it's still a csv (ie adds blank lines in between every line, more spaces etc). I think I'll see if I can convert to a txt file then back without messing up format

Comment: Update; I found the easiest thing to be just creating a new .txt and going with the solution above so thanks @Ywapom

Comment: There is the csv module for python that has read and write methods; that might spare you the txt step. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: yep it's a useful module; the issue is it takes an escape character and a quoting character to escape/quote any quotes or commas contained in your columns already, and you can't set both to be the empty string